# Concatenating proprocessor macro __FUNCTION__ with a string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++03

This should be trivial but I cannot seem to figure out how to concatenate `__FUNCTION__` with strings especially on GCC -- although it works on VC++ (I'm porting some code to Linux)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define KLASS_NAME  "Global"

int main()
{
    std::string msg = KLASS_NAME "::" __FUNCTION__;
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

[Online VC++ version](http://rextester.com/EXPS88243)

GCC error message

```
Test.cpp:9:36: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘__FUNCTION__’
  std::string msg = KLASS_NAME "::" __FUNCTION__;
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to Chris, apparently adjacent string literals are concatenated [[reference]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#13). So VC++ may be correct in this case, until you consider that `__FUNCTION__` is non-standard.

Comment: What's your error with gcc?

Comment: It's worth noting that `__FUNCTION__` isn't standard and that `__func__` isn't a string literal.

Comment: use stringizing operator '##' #define cocat(a,b)  a##b

Comment: @AliAkberFaiz, That's the concatenation operator and it's required to produce a valid token.

Comment: Why one earth does VC++ even accept `KLASS_NAME "::" __FUNCTION__` if its not valid? I'm assuming its not.

Comment: Not standard doesn't mean not valid. Compilers are allowed to have extensions.

Comment: @chris Fair point, and noted.

Comment: Also note that different compilers have the freedom to implement the same extension differently. It would be entirely legal for one compiler to define `__FUNCTION__` as a string literal containing the current function name and another to define it as exactly the same as `__func__`. Both are pretty reasonable, the latter being a way to mostly support code using `__FUNCTION__` with little extra effort, though it breaks code that depends on it being a string literal. I'm not personally aware of what the differences between existing implementations are here.

Comment: @chris I agree. What I still find perplexing is how VC++ manages to compile the above patently incorrect code no matter the implementation of `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: Adjacent string literals are concatenated. It's not necessarily incorrect code. That is, `"Global" "::" "main"`, after expansion, would be legal and equivalent to `"Global::main"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139506/discussion-between-olumide-and-chris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a concatenation operator and explicitly construct the string such that the right concatenation operator is found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define KLASS_NAME  "Global"

int main()
{
    std::string msg = std::string(KLASS_NAME) + "::" + __FUNCTION__;
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/vn4yra